# Some newbie questions on Git and GitKraken

Tags: git, gitkraken

I am new to the wonderful world of Git (yes, I did see the xkcd comic). I am trying Gitkraken on a Windows PC. To be clear, I need to use Git locally only - I will NOT upload any code to github nor to any external site or repository.

I ran Gitkraken and created a new repo in "mystuff\Test Kraken"

I created a new text file with notepad, wrote one line and saved it

Gitkraken sees "one file change in working directory"; I click "view changes"

Then 'stage files', I write a description and I commit the changes

I make two more changes repeating the steps above, ie I add a second line, commit the changes, then add a third line, and commit the changes.

**How do I check the differences between the first and the third commit?** If I select both in the Gitkraken window, I can't seem to find an option to compare them.

If I right click on the second version (of 3) and do revert commit, I get a **"file conflict" message**. Is this because Git now sees a mismatch between the first and the 3rd version? Does this mean that you should only revert the very last commit? **Can you ever revert a commit other than the last without creating a conflict?**

**Suppose I want to go back to the very first version, but I want to retain the 2nd and 3rd;** eg the 2nd and 3rd contain some code that doesn't work but that I want to review at a later time. How do I do that? Reverting the 2nd commit creates a conflict. Do I need **'reset master to this commit -> soft: keep all the changes' ?** I have tried that but it doesn't do anything - the file doesn't change.

**Is the right way to go back to the first version to create a branch where the first commit is?**

Say I have created another branch and am now working on A2. **If I want to go back to B, without losing the 2nd branch, how do I do that?**
----master --- -----A -- B
                              ¦
                           branch out ----- A2

**Does Gitkraken store data only in the .git folder or also somewhere else?** Eg if I move one drive to another PC and install Gitkraken on it, will I have lost anything or not?

Comment: You might want to split this into multiple questions.

Comment: Done. Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55322539/difference-between-creating-a-branch-and-doing-a-soft-reset-best-way-to-go-back and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55322462/can-you-ever-revert-a-commit-other-than-the-very-last-without-creating-a-conflic?noredirect=1#55322482

Comment: Shall I delete this question now?

Comment: You can do if your question is answered elsewhere, but it’s usually better to mark it as a duplicate (by a flag)