# Can you ever revert a commit other than the very last without creating a conflict?

Tags: git, git-revert

Let's say that I have one branch only, and the history of my commits are:

A - B - C - D

If I click on C in a GUI (like GitKraken or Git for Windows) and do "revert commit", I get a file conflict message.

Two questions:

1. Is this because the revert "undoes" the changes made in C, and GIT
   is now stuck with B and D which modify the file in different,
   incompatible ways? is that the reason?
2. If yes, does this mean that you can only revert the very last
   commit? Can you ever revert a commit other than the very last
   without creating a conflict?

### Update

Editing the question after the very helpful clarifications from @RomainValeri. I think I was making too much confusion between revert and reset. In his example below, doing

```
git revert B
```

causes the branch to go from

```
A-B-C-D
```

to

```
A-B-C-D-E
```

**If B was the only commit which changed file2.txt, and B didn't make any other changes to other files, then the new commit E created after the revert will retain all the changes made in C and D but NOT those made in B. Is this correct?**

This is because, technically, reverting means cancelling out, undoing any changes of a commit - is this correct?

Also: let's say that **I have only one file in my working directory. If B is the only commit which changes the function fun1() in my file,** while all the other commits change other functions within the same file, then **reverting B will most likely cause a conflict**, because git thinks in terms of lines in a file, not in terms of functions within a file. Is this correct?

So let's say that B changes fun1(), C changes fun2() and D changes fun3(). I then realise that the changes made at B in fun1() are wrong and I need to undo them. **If all these functions are in the same file, is there a way to undo the changes in B while retaining those in C and D?**

If, instead, each of these 3 functions is in a separate file, then it is much simpler to undo the changes of one commit without affecting the others, right?

I imagine this is, of course, one of the many reasons why a single file should never be too large nor contain too many functions doing different things, right?

Comment: Well, you could always just *resolve* the conflict?

Answer (score 6):

**Short answer :** Yes. You could *very well* revert a given commit (even an old one) and have no conflict.

---

**Why is it so?**

[`git revert`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) creates a new commit on top of the current tip of the tree, it does *not* delete the given commit, nor modifies it in any way.

You have a conflict when something is different in the [merge-base](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base) between the commit you're creating with the revert and `HEAD`.

---

Try it out for yourself with this

**Trivial example**

Given the repo tree,

```
Folder1
  file1.txt
  file2.txt
Folder2
  file3.txt
```

and following history,

```
A---B---C---D << HEAD
```

where

`A` creates all files with their contents.
`B` modifies `file2.txt`
`C` modifies `file1.txt` and `file3.txt`
`D` further modifies `file1.txt`

then the command

```
git revert B
```

would *not* create any conflict, just a fresh new commit `E` with new changes for `file2.txt`.

```
A---B---C---D---E << HEAD
```

---

**Contents of the new commit created by `git revert`** *(added after comments)*

The changes in `E` are the exact reverse changes that `B` introduced.

With `B` like this :

```
$ git show B
commit f3ba29d98c0998297126d686d03d33794cbc0f73
Author: Pythonista <some.name@some.isp>
Date:   Sun Mar 24 20:41:49 2019 +0100

    Some change

diff --git a/javascript/functions.js b/javascript/functions.js
index 543c9cb..5f166d3 100644
--- a/javascript/functions.js
+++ b/javascript/functions.js
@@ -3710,5 +3710,6 @@ function dumpLists(isMixted) {
 // end of process

 createTrigger(window, 'load', START_EVERYTHING);
+doStuff(param);
```

You would have an `E` commit containing :

```
$ git show E
commit 2ff723970e81d64f3776c081a1f96242589774b6 (HEAD -> master)
Author: Pythonista <some.name@some.isp>
Date:   Sun Mar 24 20:42:33 2019 +0100

    Revert "Some change"

    This reverts commit f3ba29d98c0998297126d686d03d33794cbc0f73.

diff --git a/javascript/functions.js b/javascript/functions.js
index 5f166d3..543c9cb 100644
--- a/javascript/functions.js
+++ b/javascript/functions.js
@@ -3710,6 +3710,5 @@ function dumpLists(isMixted) {
 // end of process

 createTrigger(window, 'load', START_EVERYTHING);
-doStuff(param);
```

Mind the `+` or `-` in front of the last diff line, meaning "addition" (+) and "deletion" (-).

---

**Finally, to say a word about the concerns at the end of your post** (which I mostly missed, for some reason) :

I don't think you should base architecture choices for your application upon source control worries. Git is quite a great tool, and it's smart enough to prevent a big part of the frequent trouble we would inevitably have without. Go for the best way to group your code along its own logic, regardless of git.

And by the way, conflict detection happens at chunk level, not file. Meaning that the same file could have been modified by two sources without provoking a conflict if they happen in different non-contiguous parts. I couldn't exactly say where's the threshold, but it's irrelevant to the point.

Comment: Let me see if I understand this: it is a conflict because, say, by reverting C I go back to B, which defines x= y, while D defines x = z in the same line of code. is that an example? Similarly, if all D does is to add another line of code at the very end, eg z = 1, this would NOT create a conflict after I revert, right?

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you're describing. "by reverting C I go back to B" sounds very wrong, what did I miss? Let's not confuse revert and reset here. Reverting `C` does **not** go back anywhere. It just creates a new commit on top. Are we ok on this?

Comment: I have never felt so stupid as since I have been trying to learn git! Does revert not undo a commit? I am confused to say the least? No? Or does reverting C create a new commit after D?

Comment: `Reset` sets the branch pointer elsewhere. `Revert` creates a new commit containing the exact reverse changes of a given commit. Don't be so mad, you're not the only one to struggle with this, it's not that easy to grasp at start. You don't sound like a stupid person to me, that's for sure :-)

Comment: So git revert B causes the tree to go from A-B-C-D to A-B-C-D-B. It's a bit clearer now. Thanks! I wish I had found this simple one-liner among the literally hundreds of pages of documentation and tutorials I have been pouring over!

Comment: Thanks :-) Just a last concern : are we clear that you meant `B'` (mind the apostrophe) at the end of your last example `A-B-C-D-B` ? I used `B'` in my example to represent the link between `B` and `B'`, but I could as well have said `A-B-C-D-E` where `E` contains the reverse changes of B.

Comment: So in your example B' (or E, or however we want to call it) is a new state which retains the changes made in C and D but does NOT have the changes made in B. In your example, this means that B' (or E) would NOT have any changes to file2.txt. Is this correct? So reverting is forward-looking while resetting is backward-looking, can we say that?

Comment: @Pythonistaanonymous No, sorry I've been unclear in my last comment. Let's say `B` contains the addition of the line `x = 0;` at the start of `file2.txt`. `B'` (or `E`) will contain the suppression of that line in that file. And have no *special* link to `B` otherwise, that's also why we often use the commit message to mention the commit we reverted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190579/discussion-between-pythonista-anonymous-and-romainvaleri).

Comment: @Pythonistaanonymous Sorry I'm about to feed my kids ;-) later today with pleasure

Comment: @Pythonistaanonymous I've edited a bit more on this last point, hopes it clears any remaining obscurities.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all the history-making operations other than straight commit in Git wind up having a merge involved somewhere.  Rebase, cherry-pick, revert, stash pop, merge of course, they all merge, just with merge bases chosen as needed.  There's even a merge option on checkout that merges using your current checkout as the base, the new commit as a tip and your worktree/index as the other tip, and merges into the new worktree/index, that can be gratifyingly handy.

For a revert, say `A---B... * ... M     master` and you `git revert B`, git looks at the changes from `B` to `A` and the changes from `B` to `M`, that's your merge. If adjacent or overlapping lines got touched in the two sets of changes, the odds some human needs to fix up the text skyrocket, so Git refuses to do it silently.  The trivial cases take seconds anyway.

Comment: About `git checkout -m` (if I understood well what you hinted at at the end of your first paragraph), I had to look it up and never used it yet, thanks for the tip :-)