# Difference between creating a branch and doing a soft reset? Best way to go back to an old working version?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-reset

Say the history of my commits is A - B - C and I have only this branch.

B was fully working. I started adding some functionality in C, but it's not working so **I need to go back to B, but I also want to retain the code I wrote in C** because I will want to review it and fix it later.
What is the best way to do it?

Is the best way to create a new branch starting from B?

What is the difference between that and doing a soft reset? I understand a soft reset doesn't delete the changes (is that correct?) but it's not clear to me how to restore those changes (the code in C), nor what the difference between a soft reset and creating a branch is.

### Aside

Git just seems needlessly arcane and obscure. I mean, the official docs define push as:

> https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push
>
> git-push - Update remote refs along with associated objects

I am sure it is technically correct, but it is hardly the most user-friendly explanation. Could they have added a comment explaining it uploads the local repository to the remote one, or something like that?

Comment: Push I don’t think has anything to do with what you want.

Comment: It doesn't. Mine was just an example of how needlessly obscure the git documentation is. It's like Sheldon Cooper of the Big Bang Theory going to the checkout in a shop and quoting the price in binary - WHY?

Comment: Haha. Yeah. I only started reading the docs one I understood the terms within it. No easy to get started with.

Comment: One of my best professors at uni always said: beware of those who try to dumb down very complex concepts, but also beware of complexity for its own sake: those who cannot explain a simple concept in a simple way either want to show off or do not really understand the concept themselves!

Answer (score 4):

All the answers here are OK.  What's missing is, well ... this is where your rant comes in. :-)  Your professor-quote here is quite [apposite](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apposite):

> One of my best professors at uni always said: beware of those who try to dumb down very complex concepts, but also beware of complexity for its own sake: those who cannot explain a simple concept in a simple way either want to show off or do not really understand the concept themselves!

Or, [as Einstein supposedly put it](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2011/05/13/einstein-simple/), "Make everything as simple as possible, but no simpler."

Unfortunately, what Git does—distributed source code control—*is* inherently complex.  Fortunately, there are some simple ways to get started.  Unfortunately, traditional books, and Git's documentation itself, do this not-so-well, in my opinion.  The [Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) is, I think, pretty good (and has the advantage of generally being up-to-date), and there are some other books that are unfortunately terribly out of date now that were pretty good, but most introductions try to start without a proper foundation.

The foundation requires some terminology as well.  This is probably where the Git manual pages fail the hardest.  They just spray terminology—sometimes *inconsistent* terminology, although this has improved over time—all over the place.  This has led to some pretty funny [web pages](https://git-man-page-generator.lokaltog.net/).  (I think a lot of introductions to Git shy away from terminology because the core foundation of Git lies in graph theory and hashing theory, and people find the mathematical aspect of those scary.)

Git itself makes things harder than necessary.  A simple existence proof of that is Mercurial.  Mercurial and Git are, at least in terms of what they do with source code, equally powerful—but those new to distributed source control have *far* fewer problems getting started in Mercurial than they do in Git.  It's not 100% clear why that is, but I think there are two key things Mercurial does differently that produce this result:

- In Mercurial, branches are global and permanent.  This is very convenient for beginning work but, at least sometimes, proves to be a trap.  Mercurial eventually added *bookmarks* that work like Git's branches.
- Mercurial does not have the thing that Git calls the *index*.

These aren't the only things—Git has a lot of other, smaller annoyances as well that just aren't there in Mercurial—but I think they are the big two.  For instance, the entire question of `git reset` doesn't occur in Mercurial because `git reset` (a) manipulates branch pointers—Mercurial has those bookmarks instead, *if* you choose to use them—and (b) manipulates the index that Mercurial doesn't even have.

#### My own answer: what's going on

Anyway, the key here is these three things.  (Here comes some terminology!)

1. In Git, a *branch name* is little more than a name-to-hash-ID mapping.  What matters are the *commits*.
2. A *commit* is a unique entity, identified by a unique hash ID like `b5101f929789889c2e536d915698f58d5c5c6b7a`, that stores—permanently<sup>1</sup> and unchangably—a snapshot of files and some metadata, *including* the hash ID(s) of some other commit(s).
3. The *index* is the area that Git actually uses to build *new* commits.

---

<sup>1</sup>Well, as permanent as the commit, anyway.  Commits eventually go away if there's no way to *find* them.  This is where branch names and graph theory come in—but we'll get to that later.

---

#### What to know about the index

Let's just start with this observation: when a commit stores a snapshot of all of your files, it keeps them in a compressed, read-only, Git-only storage form.  They're sort of frozen or freeze-dried, as it were.  No one can change them at all.  That's fine for archival—saving old source code—but completely useless for getting any *new* work done.

To get work done, you need a place where your files are unfrozen, rehydrated, readable *and* writable, in their normal everyday form.  That place is what Git calls your *work-tree*.  Git could stop here—frozen commits and flexible work-tree—and that's what Mercurial does and it works fine.  But for whatever reason, Git adds this thing it calls the *index*, or sometimes the *staging area*, or even the *cache*.  (The name used depends on who / what is doing the naming, but all three are the same thing.  Also, the index itself is more complicated than I'll go into, but we don't need to worry about these complications here.)

What the index stores is Git-ified copies of files.  They're not exactly *frozen*, but they are in the same format—the freeze-dried format, as it were.  They're not useful to *you;* they're only useful to Git.  *Why* it does this is debatable, but it does this, and you need to know about it.  *What* it does with this is that the index is how Git makes *new* commits.

When you run:

```
git commit -m "this is a terrible log message"
```

Git will package up whatever is in the index *right now*, along with your metadata—your name and email address and the log message and so on—and turn that into a new commit.  The stuff in your *work-tree*, where you're doing your work, is entirely irrelevant!  The fact that everything is already prepared—already freeze-dried, as it were—is what makes `git commit` so fast.  Mercurial's `hg commit`, which commits what's in your *work-tree*, has to check every file *in* your work-tree to see if it's the same as the previous one or not, and if not, prepare the freeze-dried form for the commit.  So in a big project you run `hg commit` and then go out for coffee or whatever.<sup>2</sup>  But with Git, if you change a file in the work-tree, Git makes *you* run:

```
git add file
```

every time.  This *copies* the file—while freeze-drying or Git-ify-ing it—into the index.

Hence, the index *always contains the next commit you're proposing to make*.  If you make some changes to the work-tree, and want them in your next commit, *you* have to explicitly copy them into the index before you run `git commit`.  You *can* use `git commit -a` to have Git scan your work-tree and do the `add`s for you, making Git act the way Mercurial would if you were using Mercurial.  That's certainly convenient and lets you not think about the index, or even pretend it's not there.  But I think it's a bad plan because then `git reset` becomes inexplicable.

---

<sup>2</sup>It's usually not *that* bad, and in a small project the difference is nearly undetectable.  Mercurial uses a lot of cache tricks to speed this up as much as it can, but—unlike Git—it *keeps those out of the way of the user*.

---

#### Commits

Now let's look closely what what, exactly, goes into a commit.  I think the best way to see this is to look at an actual commit.  You can look at your own with:

```
git cat-file -p HEAD
```

but I'll show this one from the Git repository for Git like this:

```
$ git cat-file -p b5101f929789889c2e536d915698f58d5c5c6b7a | sed 's/@/ /'
tree 3f109f9d1abd310a06dc7409176a4380f16aa5f2
parent a562a119833b7202d5c9b9069d1abb40c1f9b59a
author Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1548795295 -0800
committer Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1548795295 -0800

Fourth batch after 2.20

Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
```

Note the `tree` and `parent` lines, which refer to additional hash IDs.  The `tree` line represents the saved source code snapshot.  It might not be unique!  Suppose you make a commit, then later, go back to an old version but save that as a *new* commit on purpose.  The new commit can *re-use* the original commit's `tree`, and Git will do just that, automatically.  This is one of many tricks Git has up its sleeves for compressing archived snapshots.

The `parent` line, though, is how Git commits become a *graph*.  This particular commit is [`b5101f929789889c2e536d915698f58d5c5c6b7a`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b5101f929789889c2e536d915698f58d5c5c6b7a).  The commit that comes *before* this commit is [`a562a119833b7202d5c9b9069d1abb40c1f9b59a`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a562a119833b7202d5c9b9069d1abb40c1f9b59a), which is a *merge commit:*

```
$ git cat-file -p a562a119833b7202d5c9b9069d1abb40c1f9b59a | sed 's/@/ /'
tree 9e2e07ce274b0a5a070d837c865f6844b1dc0de8
parent 7fa92ba40abbe4236226e7d91e664bbeab8c43f2
parent ad6f028f067673cadadbc2219fcb0bb864300a6c
author Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1548794876 -0800
committer Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1548794877 -0800

Merge branch 'it/log-format-source'

Custom userformat "log --format" learned %S atom that stands for
the tip the traversal reached the commit from, i.e. --source.

* it/log-format-source:
  log: add %S option (like --source) to log --format
```

This commit has *two* `parent` lines, giving two more commits.  That's what makes this a merge commit in the first place.

What all this means is that if we throw out the notion of looking at the source code (we can bring it back any time by using the `tree` lines from each commit—every commit has one), we can view the commits themselves as just a linked series of nodes in a graph, each with its own unique hash ID, each of which remembers the hash ID of some predecessor or *parent* nodes.

We can draw these like this:

```
A <-B <-C
```

for a simple three-commit repository, or:

```
...--I--J--M--N
  \       /
   K-----L
```

for a more complicated repository with a merge as the parent of the *last* commit (on the right).  We use one uppercase letter to stand in for the actual, apparently-random hash ID, because hash IDs are unwieldy (but single letters are pretty wieldy).  The arrows, or connecting lines, from a child commit back to its parent(s) are the `parent` lines in the actual commit.

Remember, again, that *all these commits are frozen in time, forever*.  We cannot change any aspect of any of them.  We can of course make a *new* commit (from the index as usual).  If we don't like commit `C` or commit `N`, we can make a replacement for it, e.g.:

```
     D
    /
A--B--C
```

Then we can bend `C` out of the way and use `D` instead:

```
A--B--D
    \
     C
```

These are the same *graph*, we're just looking at it differently.

#### Branch names (and other names but we won't cover them here)

These graph drawings are neat and simple and, I'll argue, the way to reason about your Git repository.  They show the *commits*, and they hide the ugly hash IDs from us.  But Git does actually *need* the hash IDs—that's how Git retrieves the commits—and we're going to need to remember the *last* hash ID of any one of these chains.  The reason we only need the *last* one should be obvious now: if we grab hold of, say, commit `D`, well, commit `D` stores the *actual* hash ID of commit `B` inside itself.  So once we know `D`'s hash, we use `D` to find `B`.  Then we use `B` to find `A`, and—since `A` is the very first commit and therefore has *no* parent—we can stop and rest.

So we need one more addition to our drawing here.  What we need is a *branch name*.  The name simply points to (i.e., contains the actual hash ID of) the last commit!  We can draw this as:

```
A--B--D   <-- master
    \
     C
```

The *name*, `master`, holds the *hash ID* of the last commit.  From there we find the previous commits.  What Git stores for us is:

- all of the commits, by hash ID
- some set of names, each of which holds *one* hash ID

and that—except for all the complications with index and work-tree—is how Git works.  To make a *new* commit `E`, we just snapshot the index, add the metadata (our name, email address, etc) including the hash ID of commit `D`, and write that into the commit database:

```
        E
       /
A--B--D   <-- master
    \
     C
```

and then have Git *automatically* update the name `master` to point to the new commit we just made:

```
        E   <-- master
       /
A--B--D
    \
     C
```

Now we can straighten out the kink:

```
A--B--D--E   <-- master
    \
     C
```

What about poor lonely commit `C`, though?  It has no name.  It has some actual big ugly hash ID, but how, without a name or memorizing that hash ID, will we ever *find* commit `C`?

The answer is that Git will eventually *delete* `C` entirely unless we give it a name.  The obvious name to use is another branch name, so let's do that:

```
A--B--D--E   <-- master
    \
     C   <-- dev
```

Now we have two branches, `master` and `dev`.  The name `master` *means* "commit `E`" and the name `dev` *means* "commit `C`", *at the moment*.  As we work with the repository and add new commits to it, the hash IDs stored under these two names will change.  This leads to our key observation: **In Git, the commits are permanent (mostly) and unchangeable (entirely), but the branch names *move*.**  Git stores the *graph*—these chains of commits with their internal arrows connecting them, in this backwards-looking fashion—for us.  We can add to it any time we want, by adding more commits.  And, Git stores a *name-to-hash-ID mapping table* for us, with branch names holding the hash ID of *starting points* (or ending points?) in the graph.

The Git terminology for those starting / ending points is *tip commit*.  The branch name identifies the tip commit.

#### `HEAD`, and `git checkout` and the index and the work-tree

Now that we have more than one branch name in our repository, we need some way to remember *which branch we're using*.  This is the main function of the special name `HEAD`.  In Git, we use `git checkout` to *select* some existing branch name, such as `master` or `dev`:

```
$ git checkout dev
```

results in:

```
A--B--D--E   <-- master
    \
     C   <-- dev (HEAD)
```

By attaching the name `HEAD` to a branch name like `dev`, Git knows which branch we're working on now.

As a crucial side effect, Git *also*:

- copies all the files from `C` into the index, ready for the next commit, and
- copies all the files from `C`/the-index into the work-tree, so we can see and use them.

Git may also need to *remove* some files, if we were on commit `E` and it has files that aren't there in `C`.  It will remove them from both the index and the work-tree.  As usual, Git makes sure that *all three* copies of every file match up.  If there is a file named `README` in commit `C`, for instance, we have:

- `HEAD:README`: this is the frozen Git-ified copy in commit `C`, now accessible under the special name `HEAD`.
- `:README`: this is the index copy.  It matches the `HEAD:README` at the moment, but we can *overwrite* it with `git add`.
- `README`: this is a regular file.  We can work with it.  Git doesn't really care very much about that—we'll need to copy it back into `:README` if we change it!

So, with one action—`git checkout master` or `git checkout dev`—we:

- re-attach `HEAD`;
- fill the index; and
- fill the work-tree

and are now ready to work, `git add` files to copy them back into the index, and `git commit` to make a new snapshot that adds to the branch and makes the branch *name* refer to the new commit.  Let's make a new commit `F` on `dev`:

```
... edit some file(s) including README ...
git add README                    # or git add ., or git add -u, etc
git commit -m "another terrible log message"
```

and now we'll have:

```
A--B--D--E   <-- master
    \
     C--F   <-- dev (HEAD)
```

Git knows to update `dev`, not `master`, because `HEAD` is attached to `dev`, not `master`.  Note, too, that since we made commit `F` from whatever is in our index right now, and we just made the index match the work-tree, now `F`, the index, and the work-tree all match up.  That's just what we'd have if we just now ran `git checkout dev`!

#### This is where `git reset` comes in

Except for the special case of an *unreachable* commit that eventually gets deleted, the graph itself can only be added-to.  The branch names, however, we can move around any time we like.  The main command for doing this is `git reset`.

Suppose, for instance, that commit `F` is awful—it's a mistake, we just want to forget it entirely.  What we need to do is move the name `dev` so that instead of pointing to `F`, it points to `C` again—`F`'s parent.

We can find the hash ID of commit `C` and, rudely, just write that *directly into* the branch name.  But if we do that, what about our index and work-tree?  They'll still match the contents of commit `F`.  We'll have the *graph:*

```
A--B--D--E   <-- master
    \
     C   <-- dev (HEAD)
      \
       F
```

but the index and work-tree won't match `C`.  If we run `git commit` again we'll get a commit that looks almost exactly the same as `F`—it will share the `tree`, and just have a different date stamp and maybe a better log message.  But maybe that's what we want!  Maybe we *wanted* to just fix our terrible log message.  In that case, making a new `G` from the current index would be the answer.

That's what `git reset --soft` does: it lets us *move the branch name* to point to a different commit, without changing the index and work-tree.  We discard `F`, then make a new `G` that's just like `F` but has the right message.  `F` has no name and eventually withers away.

But what if we just wanted to get rid of `F` entirely?  Then we'd want the index and work-tree to match commit `C`.  We'll let `F` wither away as before.  But to get the index and work-tree to match `C`, we need `git reset --hard`.

Because the index and work-tree *are* separate entities, we can choose to go halfway.  We can move the name `dev` to point to `C`, replace the *index* contents with those from `C`, but leave the *work-tree* alone.  That's what `git reset --mixed` does, and `git reset --mixed` is actually the default for `git reset` so we don't even need the `--mixed` part.

All three of these actions have different end-goals: `git reset --soft` was for *re-do the commit*, `git reset --hard` was for *throw away the commit entirely*, and `git reset --mixed` doesn't have a clear usage in this particular example.  So why are they all spelled `git reset`?  That's where your rant applies again: they probably *shouldn't* be.  They're related in that Git has these three things it can do with branch-name-to-commit-hash, and index and work-tree contents:

1. move the branch name
2. replace or keep the index contents
3. replace or keep the work-tree contents

and `git reset` will either do step 1 and stop (`git reset --soft`), or do steps 1 and 2 and stop (`git reset --mixed` / the default), or do all three and stop (`git reset --hard`).  But their *purposes* aren't related: Git is confusing mechanism ("*how* we get from here to there") with goal ("get to there").

#### Conclusion

> Say the history of my commits is A - B - C and I have only this branch.

OK:

```
A--B--C   <-- branch (HEAD)
```

> I need to go back to B, but I also want to retain the code I wrote in C

OK.  Clearly what we'll want is one name identifying commit `B` and another one identifying commit `C`.  But we also need to concern ourselves with the index and work-tree!

There's only one index and one work-tree,<sup>3</sup> and those *aren't* copied by `git clone`.  Only the *commits* are permanent.  So if you have anything unsaved in your index and/or your work-tree, you probably should save it now.  (By committing, probably—and you can use `git stash` to make commits that aren't on *any* branch, but let's not go there, at least not yet.)  Let's assume you don't, so as to remove the question entirely.

The *graph* won't change.  You just need to add a new name.  There are lots of ways to do that, but for illustration, let's do it this way: let's start by creating a new branch name that *also* points to commit `C`, which we'll call `save`.  To do that, we'll use `git branch`, which can create new names pointing to existing commits:

```
$ git branch save
```

The default for where the new name points is to use the *current* commit (via `HEAD` and the current branch name), so now we have:

```
A--B--C   <-- branch (HEAD), save
```

`HEAD` has not moved: it's still attached to `branch`, which still points to `C`.  Note that both branches identify the same commit `C`, and all three commits are on both branches.<sup>4</sup>

Now that we have the name `save` saving the hash ID of `C`, we're free to move the name `branch` to point to commit `B`.  To do that, we'll use `git reset`.  We'd like to have our index and work-tree match commit `B` too, so we want `git reset --hard`—which will *replace* our index and work-tree, which is why it was important to make sure we didn't need to save anything from them:

```
$ git reset --hard <hash-of-B>
```

giving:

```
A--B   <-- branch (HEAD)
    \
     C   <-- save
```

There are, of course, a lot of other options.  For instance, we could leave `branch` pointing to `C` and create a *new* name pointing to `B`:

```
A--B   <-- start-over
    \
     C   <-- branch (HEAD)
```

and to do that we could use:

```
$ git branch start-over <hash-of-B>
```

Since we didn't move `HEAD`, there is no need to disturb the index and work-tree in any way.  If we had uncommitted work we could now run `git add` if needed (to update the index if needed) and `git commit` to make a new commit `D` that would have `C` as its parent.

---

<sup>3</sup>This is actually not true.  There's one *main* work-tree and it has one *main* index.  You can create as many temporary index files as you like, and since Git 2.5, you can add auxiliary work-trees whenever you like.  Each added work-tree has its own separate index—the index indexes / caches the work-tree, after all—and its own `HEAD` so that each can, and in fact must, be on a different branch.  But again, that's not something you need to worry about yet.  Creating a temporary index is really just for special-purpose actions: for instance, that's *how* `git stash` commits your current work-tree without messing with other things.

<sup>4</sup>This is where Git and Mercurial differ enormously: in Mercurial, every commit is on *exactly one branch*, where it remains forever.  You literally *can't* make two branch names that identify the same commit.  Mercurial also doesn't use this *branch name equals tip commit and other commits are implied by walking the graph* trick.

---

#### There's a trick for hash IDs

I'm just going to mention this in passing here.  Above, we had a lot of cases where you probably have to run `git log` and cut-and-paste big ugly hash IDs.  We already know that a *name*, like a branch name, lets us use the name instead of the ID.  Instead of writing out the hash ID of `C` as pointed-to by `branch` or by `save`, we can just use the name:

```
git show save
```

for instance will extract commit `C`, then extract commit `B`, compare the two, and show us what's different in the snapshots in `B` and `C`.  But we can go one better:

```
git show save~1
```

means: *Find commit `C`.  Then, step back one parent link.*  That's commit `B`.  So `git show` will now extract the snapshots in `B` and *its* parent `A`, compare the two, and show us what we changed in `B`.  The tilde `~` and hat `^` characters can be used as *suffixes* on any *revision specifier*.  The complete description of how to specify revisions (commits or commit ranges, mostly) is documented in [the gitrevisions manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions).  There are a *lot* of ways to do it!

---

Some years ago, I tried my hand at starting a book that would use *both* Git *and* Mercurial as a way to get people started with graph-and-hash-based distributed source code control.  Unfortunately most of the work on that happened between jobs, and I haven't been between-jobs for years now, so it's stalled and getting stale.  But for those who want to see what's there, it's [here](http://web.torek.net/torek/tmp/book.pdf).

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! I don't have the time to go over this now, but will read this with keen interest!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the commit `C` as a commit and work from `B` again, you will need a new branch.
I would suggest doing a new branch from `C` and hard-resetting `master` (or whatever your main working branch is) to `B`.

You will then be left with this (I added a new commit for clarity):

```
D      master
| C    review-c branch
|/
B
|
A
```

A soft reset to `B` will remove the commit `C` and stage the changes you made in `C` (same as if you made the changes for `C` yourself and did a `git add` of them).

Comment: What is the difference between 1) doing a new branch from C and hard-resetting master to B and 2) doing a new branch from B?

Comment: The only difference is where the `master` branch will be after doing it but that is entirely arbitrary. I chose this option because you said you want to review the code in `C` later which I understood as wanting to keep the code around but not in the branch you are developing on.

Answer (score 1):

`<rant-adressing on>`

*You have awoken [the Ancients](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55328041/1057485). Be very afraid.*

`<rant-adressing off>`

;-)

---

For the problem at hand, if you want to keep changes in C for later but keep on working from the B state which is better, you have a number of ways to do that. I'd do a new branch* and reset the old one.

**branch creation / hard reset method**

```
# create your backup branch for these failed changes
git checkout -b to-be-reviewed

# take your branch to its previous state
git checkout -
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

---

But you could also, as you considered, use `git reset --soft`. If you want to compare uses, here's how you could have proceeded with it :

**branch creation / soft reset method**

```
# undo last commit (C) but keep the changes in the working tree
git reset --soft HEAD^

# create a new branch and commit on it
git checkout -b to-be-reviewed
git commit -m "Your message"
```

Then your original branch points at B and `to-be-reviewed` has all recent (though non-working) changes.

---

Lastly, this is a use-case for [`git stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) :

**no new branch / stash method**

```
# reset your branch to state B
git reset --soft HEAD^

# stash your changes with a title for easier reuse
git stash save "Failed changes XYZ"
```

And at this point you can later inspect this stash with `git stash list` / `git stash show`.

* *(As ElpieKay [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55322702/1057485) very appropriately, tags could be considered instead of branches for this use. Overall reasonning is the same when it comes to resets anyway)*

Comment: With a soft reset the branch becomes A-B-C-B , right? This much I think I sort of get. What I don't get is: after a soft reset, where do the changes in C go? In the staging area? But won't there be a conflict when I start to make new changes and will have to put those new changes in the staging area, too?

Comment: No. With a (soft or hard, whatever) reset your branch goes `A-B`. Don't you confuse reset and revert :-) After a soft reset the changes go in the working tree, and the staging area.

Comment: So I do a soft reset and the changes which I have undone are in staging. But, as I continue to work, my new changes will also go in the staging area. Isn't there a conflict between new changes and old changes?

Comment: @Pythonistaanonymous No, conflicts happen only upon merge resolution (and similar siuations, like cherry-pick, which in fact uses a merge behind the scenes), in some cases. If you're not trying to merge something but just modify the files in your working tree, no reason for a conflict. And if you want to avoid mixing the first set of changes and the new things you're modifying, just commit in-between.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, I suggest that 1) you create a branch or a tag at `C` so that you can review it when you want to, and 2) reset your branch to `B` so that the changes of `C` are exluded from the branch.

```
# create a branch from C
git branch foo C

# create a tag at C
git branch bar C

# reset your branch to B
git checkout <your_branch>
git reset B --hard

# review C
git show foo
git show bar
```

To some degree, a tag is more stable than a branch. `foo` may move to another commit by an accidential command. `bar` always points at `C` unless you intend to move it to another commit. `bar` is considered as an alias of `C`.